# Font awesome is not loading first time in ipad/iphone and never in Mac (Safari)

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, font-awesome

On both iphone and ipad (both Chrome and Safari) they didn't load initially, but as soon as I do a refresh, they are there.

They didn't load on a Mac (Safari) but on Chrome they load immediately the first time.
On Android and Windows, they are there all the time !!!

My site is running on ubuntu (16.04), php (7.0) and the fonts are not cdn but locally. You have an idea? I tested a lot of things and do a lot of research.

I've tried to add the mimes (woff2) in the mime.types (the woff was already there).

Here's the content in my css file :

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype');
   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), 
   url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), 
   url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: CSS file might have just been cached

Comment: I've emptied the cache... Each time, the first time (on Apple product), it's not loading. When I do a refresh, the icons appear

Comment: What do you mean by "first time." Are you using a different iOS device every time to test it? Or is it the first time you open the browser after closing it or something else?

Comment: The cache is emptied. I open either Chrome or Safari with my website link... I navigate thru my website and the font aren't there until I do a refresh. Once the refresh is done, all the fonts are there. (It's do that in both Chrome and Safari)